# Calculate the weight percent of limestone in a rock sample

Tags: homework, inorganic-chemistry, stoichiometry

A 1.245 g sample of limestone ($\ce{CaCO3}$) is pulverized and then treated with 30 mL of 0.035 M $\ce{HCl}$. The excess acid requires 11.56 mL of 1.010 M $\ce{NaOH}$ to be neutralized. Calculate the %wt of limestone in the rock.

The first balanced equation would be:

$$\ce{CaCO3 + 2HCl -> CaCl2 + H2O + CO2}$$

Then:

$$\ce{HCl + NaOH -> H2O + NaCl}$$

I figured out the moles of $\ce{CaCO3}$ if that's useful for this problem 1.245 g of $\ce{CaCO3}$ / 100.089 g (molar mass)= 0.0124 M

I have this but I don't know the next steps on how to solve the problem.

Comment: Please note that the [homework policy](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange) on this site requires you 
to show some personal effort.

Comment: I have the two balanced equations CaCO3+ 2HCl --> CaCl2+H2O+ CO2

Comment: Great.  So post them.

Comment: Please check the original question. Are you sure about the concentration of the hydrochloric acid?

Answer (score 2):

The question is a bit misleading ;)

Your calculation of the moles of $\ce{CaCO3}$ would be correct if the rock sample would be pure 100% calcium carbonate. But then, all the titration would be a waste of time: There's 100 wt-% $\ce{CaCO3}$ in pure $\ce{CaCO3}$.

So, there's apparently something else in the rock sample (that doesn't disturb the titration).

However, what you know for sure is:

- the **stoichiometry** of the reaction between $\ce{CaCO3}$ and $\ce{HCl}$. With other words: How many moles of $\ce{HCl}$ are needed to react one mole of $\ce{CaCO3}$
- concentration and volume of the $\ce{HCl}$ **used in excess** to neutralize all the $\ce{CaCO3}$
- concentration and volume of the $\ce{NaOH}$ to neutralize all the $\ce{HCl}$ that is left **after** reacting all $\ce{CaCO3}$

---

**HINT:**

Did you consider to solve the **back titration** experiment by starting with the second neutralisation step?

> If 11.56mL of a 1.010 M $\ce{NaOH}$ was used to neutralize the remaining $\ce{HCl}$, how much was left of it? Compare that with the initial amount...

Comment: I don't know how to do back titration is there a formula?

Comment: I think the exercise is making the assumption that there is acid inert components to the rock.

Comment: @Lighthart Yes, that's exactly what I tried to explain.

Answer (score 1):

1. Calculate the amount of excess acid:

$$\mathrm{x mol HCl = 11.56mL NaOH \times \frac{1.010 mol NaOH}{1000mL}\times \frac{1 mol HCl}{1mol NaOH} = 0.01167 mol HCl }$$

2. Determine the amount of acid originally added:

$$\mathrm{x mol HCl = 30 mL HCl \times \frac{0.035 mol NaOH}{1000mL}= 0.0011 mol HCl }$$

3. Realize more acid was neutralized than was originally added.  There must be an error in the question some where.